# simple query to generate the o/p with sql

Tags: sql, oracle

table contains

```
column1
A
B
C
D
E
```

simple query to display output as

```
column1
B
E
A
C
D
```

i tried using

```
select * from table order by rowid;
```

iz der any other exact way to fetch the desired result?

Comment: What exactly should be the order of the output?

Comment: are there any other columns in the table that can be sorted?

Comment: tiz iz d oly requirement ..column1 is oly column in ..they hav mentioned it as simple query.

Comment: We need to know the logic to the `ORDER`, or is it an arbitrary order?

Comment: What does your `select *...` query give as a result?

Comment: @ssushmanth - there are plenty of ways you can do this (though sometimes they get ugly) but we need to know the sorting rules. We could give you answers that work for your A, B, C, D, E values, but how would F, G, etc. be sorted? And according to the AskTom site (a resource I trust), [`ROWID` is not reliable for sorting by "order added"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:912210644860).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY CASE column1 WHEN 'B' THEN 1 
         WHEN 'E' THEN 2
         WHEN 'A' THEN 3
         WHEN 'C' THEN 4
         WHEN 'D' THEN 5 END
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7590c/3) an sqlfiddle with a demo.
And the results are:

```
╔═════════╗
║ COLUMN1 ║
╠═════════╣
║ B       ║
║ E       ║
║ A       ║
║ C       ║
║ D       ║
╚═════════╝
```

Comment: lol, +1 I thought of the exact same thing... XD

Answer (score 2):

Other alternative for the Lamak's solution maybe it could be this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY 
  DECODE(column1,'B',1,
               'E',2,
               'A',3,
               'C',4,
               'D',5)
```

You can try this **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d04cd/1)**.

**[DECODE reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)**.

Comment: +1 for the alternative. But my username is Lamak, not Lamark :-)